# Xamarin - DIY tabbed page using stack layouts in a grid

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have been asked to produce a bottom-tabbed page to work with our app on both iOS and Android.
The icons on the tab items are to be the correct color of the icons I was given, and cannot be the tinted gray when unselected.

Is it feasible to do this using stack layouts within a grid, so I can retain the icon colors, and if so, is it possible to anchor the grid at the bottom of the device screen so it mimics the behavior of a tabbed page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you mention are definitely feasible. I think a lot of it can also be achieved using custom renderers on the existing `TabbedPage` control though. You could also create your own version of `TabbedPage` to suit your needs. I think the hardest to pull off if you use the existing TabbedPage and tweak that might be putting the tabs at the bottom in Android but it should definitely be possible. Especially the color requirements are easily fixed using `TintColor` on iOS.

I would not go the totally custom control route unless the things I mentioned above do not get you the result you're looking for.

**Update**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(TabbedPageCustom))]
namespace Sample.iOS 
{     
    public class TabbedPageCustom : TabbedRenderer      
    {         
        public TabbedPageCustom ()         
        {             
            TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Black;             
            TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue;             
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;         
        }     
    } 
}
```

http://motzcod.es/post/138225183932/tintcolor-selectedimage-xamarin-forms-ios
http://motzcod.es/post/157544468267/xamarin-forms-android-selected-and-unselected-tab-colors

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I already have the tab at the bottom in Android, just struggling with the images.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the images? Most of it can be done through the appearance framework by using `UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes` and setting `TabBarItem.SelectedImage` on iOS. Those should give you the option to set the images and their labels to all the colors you'd want.

Comment: I'm trying to show the images on the tabbed page as they are, not as gray-out outlines, as you normally see.  Basically I have 5 tab items, 4 of thse can be gray, but the middle has to be a green cross.  On setting the image it appears as a gray-out version, then shows the correct green version when clicked, so I'm looking for it to show the correct version of the image whether it's selected or not

Comment: Then you will need a custom renderer for `TabbedPage`. When you set the TintColor for the tabbed page it actually colors the images you provide to the color you set. By setting the `SelectedImage` and `Image` for the individual `TabBarItems` in this custom renderer you can also have separate images for these states. I updated my answer with a quick sample.

Comment: Thanks, will accept your answer,  you say this is for iOS, is it similar for Android?

Comment: Android doesn't have icons by default. I added two tutorials in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do it with Content View. This will give you the swipe option as well. 
You can make the master layout using a StackLayout or Grid.

Sample :

```
<Stacklayout>
<ContentView />
<Stacklayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
<Button />
<Button />
</Stacklayout>
</Stacklayout>
```

You can also achieve the same via CustomRenderer as iOS already renders the tabs at bottom. For android you can use TabHost and place it at the bottom. This would give you a more native look and feel.

This should give you something to look at https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/